# Smooth scrolling not working from all links

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a page with three on-page links that should all smoothly animate scrolling to the anchor link, but only the first link scrolls smoothly. Incidentally, the first link is the only link "above" the anchored link. The other two links, which ignore the smooth scrolling script, are located above the link and first scroll to the top of the page before snapping to the anchored link. How can I configure it so that the links beneath the anchored link scroll up smoothly to the anchored link, without scrolling to the top first?

Here's what I have:

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".cta-btn a");

for (const link of links) {
  link.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const href = this.getAttribute("href");
  const offsetTop = document.querySelector(href).offsetTop;
  $("input[id$='input']").focus();
  $(".guitar-service-address>span.placeholder-location").hide();
  scroll({
    top: offsetTop,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}

$('#input').on("focus", function() {
  $(".guitar-service-address>span.placeholder-location").hide();
});

$(function() {
  $("span.placeholder-location + input").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length) {
      $(this).prev('span.placeholder-location').hide();
    } else {
      $(this).prev('span.placeholder-location').show();
    }
  });
  $("span.placeholder-location").click(function() {
    $(this).next().focus();
  });
});

if ($(window).width() < 768) {
  $(".placeholder-above").append($(".placeholder-float").text());
}
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 990px;
}

.tab-placeholder {
  display: none;
}

input[id="input"] {
  width: 500px;
}

.guitar-service-address>span.placeholder-location {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 6px 8px;
  color: #686e74;
  cursor: auto;
  font: Helvetica 15px/20px bold;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 1;
}

.guitar-service-address>.placeholder-location>.font-alt {
  color: #686e74;
  font-weight: normal;
}

input {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 11pt;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
}

.help-block {
  font-size: 90%;
}

.test {
  padding: 20px;
}

.section {
  padding: 150px 20px;
}

#head {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

#ckav {
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
}

#cta {
  background-color: #fdfd4d;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  input[id="input"] {
    width: 300px;
  }
  span>.placeholder-float {
    display: none;
  }
  .tab-placeholder {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="section" id="head">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>CTA</h2>
    <div>
      Leverage agile frameworks to provide a robust synopsis for high level overviews. Iterative approaches to corporate strategy foster collaborative thinking to further the overall value proposition. Organically grow the holistic world view of disruptive
      innovation via workplace diversity and empowerment.
    </div>
    <div class="cta-btn">
      <a href="#ckav">Check your guitar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="section" id="ckav">
  <div class="container test">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="placeholder-above"></div>
        <div class="guitar-service-address">
          <span class="placeholder-location"><span class="placeholder-float">Find guitar repair specialist. </span><span class="font-alt">Enter your guitar make and model...</span></span>
          <input id="input" type="text" />&nbsp;
        </div>
        <p class="help-block">What is this?</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="section" id="stuff">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Stuff</h2>
    <div>
      Collaboratively administrate empowered markets via plug-and-play networks. Dynamically procrastinate B2C users after installed base benefits. Dramatically visualize customer directed convergence without revolutionary ROI. Efficiently unleash cross-media
      information without cross-media value.
    </div>
    <div class="cta-btn">
      <a href="#ckav">Check your guitar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="section" id="cta">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>CTA</h2>
    <div>
      Leverage agile frameworks to provide a robust synopsis for high level overviews. Iterative approaches to corporate strategy foster collaborative thinking to further the overall value proposition. Organically grow the holistic world view of disruptive
      innovation via workplace diversity and empowerment.
    </div>
    <div class="cta-btn">
      <a href="#ckav">Check your guitar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Codewalker/6or8pwjx/

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the CSS. you don't even need Javascript/Jquery.

```
* {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

[Check it in action on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ynfmwe4/)

Comment: That's just what we want, but browser support for 'scroll-behavior' is weak at the moment.

Comment: @linnse It is not that bad https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-behavior

Comment: @linnse 76.41% overall supported, 83.09% on desktop, 72.71% on mobile.